# copy and paste between two txt file

Tags: bash, awk, sed

Hi I am new to bash and using sed need a little help

I have two txt files i need to copy and paste between them the first file I know what the text is and placed of the text but the second txt file I don't know the text but I do know the placed of the text is.

In file1 put the two text words or numbers from file2 and place them like I show below.

When I create file2 all I am going to know about it will have two words or numbers on the same line4

I have been trying with this

```
sed $'10{e sed "4!d" /home/Desktop/file1.txt\n;d}'  /home/Desktop/file2.txt
```

and

```
awk 'NR==4{a=$0}NR==FNR{next}FNR==10{print a}4' /home/Desktop/file2.txt /home/Desktop/file1.txt
```

This is what my files would look like

**file1.txt**

```
cat
hat
sat
fat
mat
rat
```

**file2.txt**

```
line1
line2
line3
text1 text2
line5
```

I need it to look like this

**file1.txt**

```
cat
hat
sat text1
fat text2
mat
rat
```

thanks for any help

Comment: Couple of questions here, 1- is it always text line in 2nd file which needs to be looked on to be inserted in file1? 2- what should be logic of inserting data in file1? Is it specific text or lines? Kindly provide more details how to achieve your shown sample expected output and let us know then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E '1{x;s#^#sed -n 4p file2#e;x};3{G;s/\n(\S+).*/ \1/};4{G;s/\n\S+//}' file1
```

Stuff the line from file2 into the hold space when processing file1 and append and manipulate that line when needed.

A more explicit explanation:

By default, sed reads each line of a file. For each cycle, it  removes the newline, places the result in the pattern space, goes through a sequence of commands, re-appends the newline and prints the result e.g. `sed '' file` replicates the `cat` command. The sed commands are usually placed between `'...'` and represent a cycle, thus:

`1{x;s#^#sed -n 4p file2#e;x}`

- `1{..}` executes the commands between the ellipses on the first line of file1. Commands are separated by `;`'s
- `x` sed provides two buffers. After removing the newline that delimits each line of a file, the result is placed in the pattern space. Another buffer is provided empty, at the start of each invocation, called the hold space. The `x` swaps the pattern space for the hold space.
- `s#^#sed -n 4p file2#e` this inserts another sed invocation into the empty hold space and evaluates it by the use of the `e` flag. The second invocation turns off implicit printing (`-n` option) and then prints line 4 of file2 only.
- `x` the hold space is now swapped with the pattern space.Thus, line 4 of file2 is placed in the hold space.

`3{G;s/\n(\S+).*/ \1/}`

- `3{..}` executes the commands between the ellipses on the third line of file1.
- `G` append the contents of hold space to the pattern space using a newline as a separator.
- `s/\n(\S+).*/ \1/` match on the appended hold space and replace it by a space and the first column.

`4{G;s/\n\S+//}`

- `4{..}` executes the commands between the ellipses on the fourth line of file1.
- `G` append the contents of hold space to the pattern space using a newline as a separator.
- `s/\n\S+//` match on the appended hold space and remove the newline and the first column, thus leaving a space and the second column.
  m

Comment: @spywill what version of gnu sed are you using?

Comment: I suspect the RHS of the first substitute command contains the file path of `file2` and this is interfering with the delimiters, see edit.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to append the fields of the 4th line of file2.txt
to the 3rd and the following lines of file1.txt, how about:

```
awk 'FNR==NR {if (FNR==4) split($0, ary, " "); next} {print $0 " " ary[FNR - 3 + 1]}' /home/Desktop/file2.txt /home/Desktop/file1.txt
```

Result:

```
cat
hat
sat text1
fat text2
mat
rat
```